# swift firestore 取得データでAPIリクエストをしたい

Tags: swift, firebase, array

swift firestore のデータ取得について質問をさせていただきます。

#### 実現したいこと

簡単な動画再生アプリを作成しております。お気に入りの動画のvideoIdをfirestoreに保存までしていて、お気に入り画面で保存したvideoIdを用い、お気に入りにした動画を見れるようにしたいと思っております。

#### 不明点

videoId取得後、配列に格納したvideoIdを順番にAPIリクエストを行うためにどのように書いていくのが良いか。

よろしくお願いいたします。

**環境**
Xcode 12
iOS 14

```
//firestoreのvideoIdを配列に格納
private var videoIds: [String] = []

//firestoreのvideoIdを取得
func fetchFirestoreVideoId(){
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
    let userRef = Firestore.firestore().collection(Const.UserPath).document(uid)
    userRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
        if let document = document, document.exists {
            let dataDescription = document.data().map(String.init(describing:)) ?? "nil"
            print("Document data: \(dataDescription)")
            // DocumentにあるvideoIdを配列に格納したい


        } else {
            print("Document does not exist")
        }
    }
}

    //②Youtube検索情報を取得
private func fetchYoutubeSerachInfo() {

    // videoIdを取得した後、YoutubeAPIリクエストのパラメーターとして取り出したvideoIdを入れたい
    let params = ["q": "q4NPu-bfxrE"]

    API.shared.request(path: .search, params: params, type: Video.self) { (video) in
        self.videoItems = video.items
        let id = self.videoItems[0].snippet.channelId
        self.fetchYoutubeChannelInfo(id: id)
    }
}
```

参考にしたドキュメント: [firebase 公式](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_a_document)

---

[image: firestore]

**videoId取得後、配列に格納したvideoIdを順番にAPIリクエストを行う**
[image: videoId取得後、配列に格納したvideoIdを順番にAPIリクエストを行う]

質問が重複しているとの指摘を伺いましたので、質問内容を修正いたしました。

Comment: 回答される方へ　https://teratail.com/questions/295300

Answer (score 0, accepted):

自己解決いたしました。documentのdataの中にある"videoId"を配列として取得、for文で取得したvideoIdを順番にAPIリクエストをかけて、結果を取得しました。

```
//FireStoreのvideoIdを配列に格納
private var videoIds: [String] = []

//firestoreのvideoIdを取得
private func fetchFirestoreVideoId(){

    guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
    let userRef = Firestore.firestore().collection(Const.UserPath).document(uid)

    userRef.getDocument { [self] (document, error) in
        if let document = document, document.exists {
            let userDic = document.data()

            //documentのdataの中にある"videoId"を配列として取得
            if let videoIds: [String] = userDic!["videoId"] as? [String] {
                // videoIdsの要素であるvideoIdを取り出しAPIリクエスト
                for videoId in videoIds {
                    //取得したvideoIdをもとにYoutube検索情報を取得
                    fetchYoutubeSerachInfo(videoId: videoId)
                }
            }
        } else {
            print("Document does not exist")
        }
    }
}

    //Youtube検索情報を取得
private func fetchYoutubeSerachInfo(videoId: String) {

    // videoIdを取得した後、YoutubeAPIリクエストのパラメーターとして実行
    let params = ["q": videoId]

    API.shared.request(path: .search, params: params, type: Video.self) { (video) in
        self.videoItems = video.items
        let id = self.videoItems[0].snippet.channelId
        self.fetchYoutubeChannelInfo(id: id)
    }
}
```